# related products getProductUrl() giving url without rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, url, related-products

I'm loading my related products like this:

```
 <?php $_relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProducts(); ?>


    <?php foreach ($_relatedProducts as $_item):
       $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());  ?>


       <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">
       <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>
       </a>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

for any reason i'm getting this weird url

**example.com/catalog/product/view/id/393/s/productname/category/4/**

with `$_item->getProductUrl()`;

but the product itself has a canonical with the right url, which should be:

**example.com/productname**

how can i get this url in my loop?

I know that with a normal collection i can add ->addUrlRewrite(); and it works... but here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addUrlRewrite()->load($_item->getId()); 
In foreach, you can use 

$_item->getUrlPath();

Comment: thanks a lot but could you explain it a little bit more with my code example? i don't get how i should implement that without creating a double loop @Krishati95Dev

Comment: <?php $_relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProducts(); ?>


    <?php foreach ($_relatedProducts as $_item):
       $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addUrlRewrite()->load($_item->getId());  ?>


       <a href="<?php echo $_item->getUrlPath() ?>">
       <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>
       </a>

    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: tried it exactly like this, but i'm getting the following error:
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`. Any idea why? :-( @Krishati95Dev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614997/magento-getmodelcatalog-product-getcollection-with-addattributetoselect

Comment: unfortunately turning on Flat Catalog Category &
Use Flat Catalog Product breaks the whole shop, so i can't do that... even if i turn both on, i can't see anything at all anymore @Krishati95Dev